# Every query on pool is triggering on connection

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, pg, node-postgres

I started using PostgreSQL now, i want to have a persistent connection between the client and the database, so i don't need to create and finish a connection on each query. I found out that Pool is the better approach, so my code ended up like this:

```
const { Pool } = require('pg');

const dbConfig = {
    user: '#####################',
    password: '##########',
    database: '#########',
    host: '############',
    port: '####',
};

let pool = new Pool(dbConfig);
pool.connect();
pool.on('connect', (client) => {
    console.log('Connection Created')
});

function query(text) {
    return new Promise(((resolve, reject) =>{
        pool.query(text)
            .then((result) => resolve(result.rows))
            .catch(err => reject(err));
    }))
}

module.exports = {
    query: query
};
```

Why every time I call a query it triggers my 'Connection Created'? **Even if i take the pool.connect()** the query itself creates a connection, shouldn't it give me an error saying that there is no connection created yet? And finally, what is the best approach to reduce query times by **not having to create a connection on every query**?

Thanks for your time =)

Comment: Have you tried [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise)? You wouldn't need to deal with connections at all.

Comment: No, never, i'll give a look to it